# Cambiar el valor nulo por texto usando tipo la función de "nvl" en MySQL

Tags: mysql

Tengo una base llamada "base" que tiene una tabla llamada "Programa" en MySQL, estoy trabajando en MySQL Workbench

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en donde la columna "Lugar" tiene un valor nulo cuando el id  es 19 y 20, el objetivo es hacer una consulta que en lugar de mostrar el valor como null lo muestre como "No existe",  Intento hacer la consulta así:

Con esta consulta me dice que nvl mo es una funcion aceptada para MySQL

````
```   SELECT id, lugar, nvl(lugar,"No existe" ) as prueba 
FROM base.Programa
````

Ahora con la siguiente consulta

```
SELECT id, lugar, COALESCE(lugar,"No existe" ) * COALESCE(lugar,"Esta vacio") as prueba 
FROM base.promo
```

se muestra lo siguiente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Use COALESCE porque es permitida en MySQL
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguna sugerencia de como llegar al resultado

Gracias.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7239509/17161735

Comment: ¿Para qué pones el operador de multiplicación `*` con cadenas?.

Answer (score 3):

No veo `NULL`, pero si fuese aquello entonces:

```sql
SELECT id, lugar, ifnull(lugar,"No existe" ) as prueba 
FROM base.Programa
```

Comment: te me adelantaste XD

Comment: @Isanchezo En que bases se puede usar nvl?

Comment: @Isanchezo    Listo, ya si es null, con la función  de ifnull, he revisado y  si se puede , Gracias

Comment: @ArcanisGK507 tengo los dedos muy rápidos :3

Comment: @Cecyg NVL es nativa de oracle